# "auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check" is not among possible values for name while creating a liferay hook

Tags: hook, liferay

Am trying to create a liferay hook, to have my own authorization mechanism.
I have my authorization class ready, in portal.properties,

I have

```
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
auth.pipeline.pre=CustomAuthenticator
```

But in my eclipse, it says `"auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check" is not among possible values for name`. 
What is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't your hook work as intended or just work? In case of Liferay development I wouldn't listen to what Eclipse says. It may be that Eclipse just can't find or parse something.

Comment: @ArtemShafranov No its not working after deployment. Even though am returning SUCCESS from authenticateByEmailAddress() method of my Custom authenticator class, authentication still failing.

Comment: Can I ask you what you are trying to do here ? is that AutoLogin feature you want to implement in Liferay?

Comment: Am trying to develop a CAS(Custom authentication system) for liferay, in which after authenticating using using my CAS, i dont liferay to check in its database about the user, so all over i could find that 'auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false' is the solutions. but thats not working for me